# How can I make a dynamic matrix to calculate the mean threshold of multiple images in C++

Tags: c++, image, opencv, medical

This is the part of code that I've written to build the matrix to calculate mean threshold of specific zone in multiple images. 
The problem is that I get the value of mean threshold: `-2147483648`
(Apologies for language error)

Here is my code:

```cpp
int moyenne(cv::Mat& image, cv::Point seed) {
    double th = 0;
    int count = 0;
    int N = 3;

    for (int x = seed.x - N; x <= seed.x + N; x++) {
        for (int y = seed.y - N; y <= seed.y + N; y++) {
            if (x == seed.x && y == seed.y) {
                continue;
            }
                else {
                    int som = 0;
                    som = +(abs(int(image.at<cv::Vec3b>(seed.x, seed.y)[0])));
                        if (som == N) {
                            N++;
                        }
                        while (som <N ) {

                                th += abs(int(image.at<cv::Vec3b>(seed)[0] - image.at<cv::Vec3b>(x, y)[0]));

count++;
                        }
                }
        }
    } return th / count;
}
```

Comment: This code makes little sense to me, your `while(som <N )` loop does not alter either variable, so how would you ever get out of it?

Comment: i have a binary image and with a click mouse I get the the mean threshold of  an area wich is in white , for this i make a matrix wich  calculate the sum of te matrix for example if the matrix is 3*3 so the sum is 9  = we are in the white area so i increase the matrix to find pixel that contain 0 value =Black, so the sum <  the size of matrix  here we calulate the mean

Comment: Maybe I've gone completely code-blind, but I can't see **anywhere** in your code where you change `count` to anything other than its initial `0`. And dividing by zero gives, well ...

Comment: sorry i forget it  @AdrianMole